# How to keep an instance of user-defined ruby class in the memory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I wrote a fax.rb class in my rails app to send online fax, which will be be used very often.
I want to keep one instance of it in the memory. How do I do that?

Comment: I've never heard of Ruby's MRI paging out loaded code -- it's all in memory at once, so this question is pretty nonsensical.

Comment: Sorry for the nonsensical question, I'm new to Ruby. If I do "Fax.new" many times, only one instance be kept in the memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ruby Class *is* a singleton and therefore can have only one instance...

```
class Fax
  def self.dialup(num)
    # call the fax
  end
end
```

Another solution is :

```
class Fax
  include Singleton
  ...
end
```

Which will ensure you the same. However I've heard bad things on singletons.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm new to Ruby. Do you mean only one instance will be created and kept in the memory even if I do "Fax.new" many times?

Comment: Fax is a constant so if you call methods directly on it like Fax.dialup it'll be always the same Fax with the same state. Fax.new will create new objects each time you call it (new allocates memory for a 'new' object). But maybe you only want one @fax = Fax.new and singleton is the solution but it's generally considered bad design...